# How to prevent jackson instantiating new object in deserialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I want to create an object from a JSON string using jackson with the following structure

```
public class A {
    private int id;
    private B b;

    public A() {
        id = 5;
        b = new B(10, 20);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
public class B {
    private int first;
    private int last;

    public B(int first, int last) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
    }
}
```

If I use the following code for serialization/deserialization it fails in deserialize step
NOTE: I don't want to change the code structure and add default empty constructor for class B or using JsonProperty annotation. because class A is responsible to create B inside I need some way to prevent jackson from overriding b property of class A by instantiating a new B when it tries to deserialize class A from json string

```
    A a = new A();
    ObjectMapper b = new ObjectMapper();
    b.configure(Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    String jsonString = b.writeValueAsString(a);
    // jsonString = {"id":5,"b":{}} which is desirable in serialization but it fails in deserialization with the following statement.
    A readValue = b.readValue(jsonString, A.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

@JsonIgnore to your private B class variable.

IE:

```
@JsonIgnore
private B b;
```